# Specified the java library in the Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

We have created a CFX customer tag and a jar file. The jar files are in coldfusion server ../WEB-INF/lib. It processed successfully for years. Recently we are going to upgrade to coldfusion11 linux. For the maintenance concerns, the system admin prefer to move out these library files from server WEB-INF/lib to application local directory.

Here is the code for setting the localpath for coldfusion 10.

Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        //this.name = hash( getCurrentTemplatePath() ); // unique app name
        this.javaSettings = {
            loadPaths: [
                "/opt/WebRoot-DEV/afsapps/tp-web-apps/payroll/process/java/lib"
            ],
            loadColdFusionClassPath: true,
            reloadOnChange: true,
            watchInterval: 100,
            watchExtensions = "jar,class"
        };
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="OnRequestStart" returnType="void">
         <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true" />

         <!--- Include Application.cfm --->
         <cfinclude template="Application.cfm" />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

But it doesn't work, could find the jar file. I got this error message:
"The error message is "The CFX custom tag CFX_GenerateGarnishmentDocuments was not found in the custom tag database. You must add custom tags to the database before using them. If you have added your tag to the database, check the spelling of the tag within your template to ensure that it matches the database entry. "

I am not sure we could move the library files to local path, is this feasible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: The term "does not work" is too vague to be construed as useful information.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says - it is not enough to simply add the jar file. You must also register it in the ColdFusion Adminstrator under "Extensions->CFX Tags"  ... A CFX tag is a specific jar file that implements a native API interface to CF so it can be used *without* java. it's a special thing.

Step 1 is to get your file INTO the class path. You can do this by putting it in the Lib director, or you can specify the path via the JVM args like so:
[image]

Restart CF and then *register the CFX Tag* in the CF Administrator like so:

---

[image]

---

The class name will be part of the documentation of the CFX tag. To use it you then call it as one thing - CFX_*nameofthetag*   with attributes specified by the documentation.

---

CFX is basically a wrapper so that you can use something more complex and Java like in a simple primitive values in/out and get something coldfusiony back like a query or struct. It's designed to let you do ColdFusion *without* knowing a lot of Java. :)

Comment: I have registered the CFX tag. I added the jar file to coldfusion server ../WEB-INF/lib, it works successfully.  However, since we are going to upgrade to coldfusion11, for the maintenance concerns, our system admin prefers to move these library files to local directory instead of in coldfusion server.  We are trying to set up the local path on the application, but not sure how to work or if it is feasible.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be successful loading _on the fly_. I believe CF checks and loads CFX files on start (they are available server wide).  But you can put them wherever you wish and simply edit the JVM class path in the relevant jvm.config file. I routinely keep financial libraries in a separate folder for similar reasons to your Admin folks.

Comment: I have added the path to CF11 Admin/Server Settings/Java and JVM/coldFusion Class Path.  Where else I should to add?  You mentioned jvm.config, where is it located?

Comment: not the CF class path - the JVM class path. Should be at the bottom of the JVM.config file. FYI you should never (ever!) use the CF admin to make changes to your jvm.config file. (Muse tip).

Comment: Also - getting the class path right can be challenging. Are you on Linux? Windows?  To see if your file is loaded, look under "setting summary" in CF Admin. You will see a list of all the exgternal classes loaded. If it _is_ loaded and you are still getting an error it's probably because of name you gave the tag. It has to match what is configured internally in the jar file.

Comment: Jvm.config is in /runtime/bin on a standard install.

Comment: Mark, We are on Linux.  I am going to pass your information to our system admin.  Thanks.

Comment: Mark, so we need add the path "/opt/WebRoot-DEV/afsapps/tp-web-apps/payroll/process/java/lib" to Jvm.config file, right?

Comment: yes - that will probably work if that's home to your jar. I typically put the path + the name of the jar file to be specific.

Comment: I added the path and filename to jvm.config, but it doesn't work.  I got the error message: "service Unavailable":  # Comma separated list of shared library path
java.library.path={application.home}/lib/international,/opt/WebRoot-DEV/webtemp/garnishment.jar

# Comma separated list of shared library path for non-windows
java.nixlibrary.path={application.home}/lib, /opt/WebRoot-DEV/webtemp/garnishment.jar

java.class.path={application.home}/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib/oosdk/classes,/opt/WebRoot-DEV/webtemp/garnishment.jar

Comment: Service unavailable is not the error I would expect. I would expect class not found. Did you verify that the jar file is loaded on restart by looking at the summary page in the cf admin?